# p/Invoke WriteFile fails after 8 writes with access denied

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using p/invoke from c# to write directly to a local HD. The drive is formatted but doesn't contain any data. All I am trying to do is write 512 bytes of 0s to the drive until the drive is complete full.

the code:

```
for (double idx = 0; idx < TotalSectors; idx++)
    {
        File.Write(writeBuffer, (uint)writeBuffer.Length);  // write the buffer
        int val = pos += (int.Parse(BPS.ToString()) * int.Parse(idx.ToString()));
        File.MoveFilePointer(val);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

as you can see just iterates the process until all the sectors have been written to. However, for some reason after 8 iterations I receive an "Access Denied" error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Thanks to Xanatos - the stupid file position update has been fixed. However, File.MoveFilePointer() method takes an int. So I am currently casting val to (int). The method now iterates 14 times before throwing the "Access Denied" exception.

**Edit 2** *Borrowed Code* 
The write method looks like this:

```
 public uint Write(byte[] buffer, uint cbToWrite)
    {
        // returns bytes read
        uint cbThatWereWritten = 0;
        if (!WriteFile(_hFile, buffer, cbToWrite,
         ref cbThatWereWritten, IntPtr.Zero))
            ThrowLastWin32Err();
        return cbThatWereWritten;
    }
```

and the File.MoveFilePointer method looks like this:

```
public void MoveFilePointer(int cbToMove,
     MoveMethod fMoveMethod)
    {
        if (_hFile != null)
            if (SetFilePointer(_hFile, cbToMove, IntPtr.Zero,
             fMoveMethod) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
                ThrowLastWin32Err();
    }
```

Comment: this line smells fishy: `int val = pos += (int.Parse(BPS.ToString()) * int.Parse(idx.ToString()));` What should it do? And why on the earth `idx` is a `double`? Make it a `long`!

Comment: Wait... BPS is BytesPerSector (and you used a double! use an int or a long)... So pos is increased by the number of bytes per sector * the current sector... Wrong!

Comment: A `double` as a loop variable? Why?

Comment: @OskarBerggren Clearly because the `int` wasn't enough, and in C/C++ there is no guarantee that the `long` is bigger (on Windows it isn't, and the `long long` isn't normally teached), so using a `double` sometimes is/was a solution.

Comment: You need to do some soul searching: int val = pos += (int.Parse(BPS.ToString()) * int.Parse (idx.ToString()));  is inexplicable.

Comment: @xanatos I think you are saying "due to old habits". Though this is C#, where long is always 8 bytes, so the code should be fixed though.

Comment: In reality using a double or long is irrelevant to the question. Searching my soul for a bit of bad coding seems a little harsh - we would all be doing more soul searching than coding at that rate as few if anyone writes perfect code. Except perhaps yourself David Hefferman

Comment: Nobody writes perfect code. But looping with a floating point variable, and then converting to int via a string? That's really quite strange. What motivated you to do that? Direct disk writing requires precision. And then the two assignments in one statement. You have to work really hard and be very precise and accurate and keep a clear head when doing this stuff.

Comment: How would you convert a Double to a String?
Are you saying a Double 100.00 is less precise than a long 100 ?
Is an Int large enough to hold all the sectors of a disk? If not a conversion would be necessary.

Comment: I would not use a double to store an integer. If I had an floating point value, and needed to convert to integer, I would do so directly without strings. Why did you choose to brings text into a numeric issue? If int does not have the range, then what good is int.Parse? If I needed an integer with greater range than int, I'd use long. If you don't use @Name when you post comments, the recipient won't be notified.

Comment: Now, comparing double and long for storing integers, that's interesting. For smaller values, integers are exactly representable in a double. However, for larger values, there are integer values that cannot be represented. Since double and long are both 64 bits wide, they can hold a similar number of values. In fact, long has more distinct values than double, but let's ignore that. Tbc.

Comment: Since double can represent lots of non-integral values, it follows that long can represent more integral values than double. Therefore, for integral values, it never makes sense in terms of precision to use double over long.

Comment: Wait wait wait - I was not storing an integer - I am actually storing a large unknown value. The number of sectors on an unknown drive. I just used Int.Parse because the backend code (at that time) required it... The whole point is moot considering it has nothing to do with either the question or the answer.

Comment: Number of sectors is a whole number. You cannot have fractional numbers of sectors. At least, that's my belief. If you know different then more power to you. You don't seem willing to learn, and so I won't try and force you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int bps = ... // Use int!
long TotalSectors = ... // use long!
long pos = 0; // use long!

for (long idx = 0; idx < TotalSectors; idx++)
{
    File.Write(writeBuffer, (uint)writeBuffer.Length);  // write the buffer
    pos += bps;
    // File.MoveFilePointer(pos); // Useless, the file pointer will be moved
                                  // by the File.Write
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Done! You are increasing `pos` too much!

```
val = pos += (int.Parse(BPS.ToString()) * int.Parse(idx.ToString()));
```

ignoring `val`, and ignoring the `Parse(...ToString)` it's:

```
pos += BPS * idx;
```

So

```
idx = 0, pos += 0 (pos = 0), // here it's already wrong! you are initializing twice 
                             // the same sector!
idx = 1, pos += 1 * 512 (pos = 512), 
idx = 2, pos += 2 * 512 (pos = 1536) WRONG!
```

As a sidenote, in .net a `long` is 64 bits, so big enough for the number of sectors of an hard disk, or for its size.

Comment: Thanks Xantos - shall check it now..

Why the down votes? I can't believe people are Down voted for asking a question! That's ridiculous.

Comment: Ok now it runs for 14 iterations before throwing the "Access Denied" exception.

The File.MoveFilePointer(pos); takes as int.

Comment: @DaveGordon Tell me the bps, the TotalSector, the writeBuffer.Length and how much big is your disk

Comment: BPS = 512
TotalSector = 2097152
WriteBuffer.Length = 512 Byte[]

Comment: @DaveGordon 1gb disk?

Comment: Yeah - sorry forgot to say - it is a virtal drive for testing purposes.

Comment: @DaveGordon `File.MoveFilePointer` feels a little badly done... How would it work on a 3gb disk? Mmmh... After having finished, can you check if the disk was correctly emptied?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35592/discussion-between-xanatos-and-dave-gordon)